# How can I parse a table from a webpage in Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to parse the link **http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VZ/key-statistics?p=VZ** with code below and page does not load completely . I have tried using *webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(500000);* & *Thread.sleep(1000);* with out any success . My objective is to read table contents under **Valuation Measures** but that is never getting loaded . Any help is appreciated .

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class LocalScreenScappingTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware")
                .setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        // webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(500000);
        HtmlPage page = webClient
                .getPage("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VZ/key-statistics?p=VZ");
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(page.asText());
        // HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)
        // page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='main-0-Quote-Proxy']/section/div[2]/section/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table");

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println((new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()))
                + ": " + ex.toString());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using some parsing libraries like Jsoup: https://jsoup.org/ or get data directly from Yahoo Finance API: http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html

Comment: I tried Jsoup  and that also returns same . I will try Yahoo Finance API.

Comment: Attach logcat logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page through browser's developer tools, you'll see that the 'finance.yahoo.com' files are mostly JSON type. The HTML file of the webpage doesn't contain the table you want.
[image: Response]
You'll have to determine what file contains the table and use some Json parser to get it.